# Second row of my figure is not centered

Tags: pdftex, subfloats, minipage, subfig

I am using minipage to show my figures in the pdf file using the following code:

```
\begin{figure*}[tb] 
\begin{minipage}[b]{.28\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{images/3_tech/rollercoaster.jpg}
    \centerline{(a) Mega Coaster}\medskip
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.28\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{images/3_tech/LeagueofLegends.jpg}
    \centerline{(b) Project 360}\medskip        
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.28\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{images/3_tech/Cockpit.jpg}
    \centerline{(c) 360 Cockpit View}\medskip
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.28\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{images/3_tech/SkyDiving.jpg}
    \centerline{(d) Sky Diving}\medskip
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.28\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{images/3_tech/Etihad.jpg}
    \centerline{(e) Etihad A380}\medskip
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.28\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{images/3_tech/Elephants.jpg}
    \centerline{(f) Elephants}\medskip
\end{minipage}
\caption{Sample 2D representation scenes of 360$^\circ$ videos used in Test 1.}
\label{fig:Dataset_T1}
\end{figure*}
```

The output looks like this:
[image: It is not centered :(]

What should I do to make the second row look like the first row.

Comment: you have not specified centering so you have a standard justified paragraph Put `\centering` after `\begin{figure*}`  if you want a centred paragraph (don't use `[tb]` with `figure*` taht just has the effect of removing the float page possibility so makes it more likely the figure goes to the end of the document.

Comment: With a figure this large, you might need [p].

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for your useful comments. Putting \centering works for me after \begin{figure*}.